# Get Django sessions on Node.js

Tags: django, node.js, django-views

I'm trying to add Node.js to my web application in Django to have real time.
I'm doing the functionality of "like" as in facebook, when users click "like" AJAX will post the ID of song to domain.com:3000 (Node.js server).

I have the user ID on a session variable, but i don't know how to access to this session variable from Node.js.

Here is my code:

Node.js

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send("ID user: " + req.session.user_id);
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Working under 3000")
```

Django

```
def auth(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        autenti = JayapalBackend()
        auth = autenti.authenticate(email, password)

        if auth is not None:
            id_usuario = Usuario.objects.get(email=email).getId()
            request.session['user_id'] = id_usuario
            return HttpResponse('1')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("-1")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("-1")
```

Thanks

**EDITED**:

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined
```

Comment: You should read more about session tracking using cookies. Usually, in the browser, the session is a mere cookie that has a unique id as value. With that unique id, frameworks like django store in a temporary file, or a database all the variables that you associate with that "session". So, in your case, you should investigate where does django hold session information and figure out a way to access that information from the node.js server.

Comment: Okey, I've noticed that with a get_decode() and session id I can get the session content. But how can I get a function similar to get_decode() in node.js.

Comment: It is strange to ask for the session data of another server. Is it possible to encrypt needed data (e.g. hashing a user id) and send it as part of the GET request to Node server?